# Windows Domain Chaos - Any Solving Approach

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

we are running an old Window 2003 Server as Domain Controller (DC2003). To safely migrate to Windows 2008 R2 we added a 2008 R2 (DC2008R2) to the domain as domain controller (adprep etc.).

After dcpromo on DC2008R2 everything seemed to be ok. The new DC appeared under the "Domain Controlelrs" node.

It wasn't checked at this time, if DC2008R2 can REALLY act as domain controller.

Later we tried to shutdown DC2003 and ran into a total mess with non functional Exchange and Team Foundation Services.

After that I got the job to fix...

First i thought it could be an Problem with DC2008R2. So I removed it as Domain Controller and installed a new Windows 2008 R8 Server DC2008R2-2. I ran into similar Problems. I tried a bunch of stuff, but nothign helped. I won't list it, maybe I made an mistake, so I'm willing to redo it with your suggestions.

To have a starting point I tried the best practise analyser whicht ended up with 24 "Compatible" and 26 "Not Compatible" tests. From these 26 tests 19 read the same. (I'm translating from german, so that may to be the exact wording)

> Problem: 
>   Using the Best Practise Analyser for Active Directory Domain Services (Active Directory Domain Services Best Practices Analyzer, AD DS BPA) no data can be be gathered using the name of the forest and the domain controller DC2008R2-2.

I appreciate any suggestions, this really bothers me.

Comment: What DNS servers are hosting the AD DNS zone? Is DNS running on only the old DC? Did you add the DNS role to the new DC? Is your AD DNS zone AD integrated? Has the AD DNS zone replicated to the new DC? Are the clients configured to use the new DC for DNS?

Comment: Further: you should run netdiag / [dcdiag](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776854(v=ws.10).aspx) (the latter only available for Windows Server 2003) on both the old 2003 DC and the newly promoted 2008 R2 DC and post the output here.

Comment: @joeqwerty What DNS servers are hosting the AD DNS zone? --> DNS is installed on every DC. Is DNS running on only the old DC? --> No. Did you add the DNS role to the new DC? --> Yes. Is your AD DNS zone AD integrated? --> How can I check that, to be sure? Has the AD DNS zone replicated to the new DC? --> Yes, all DNS Information is avaiable on all DNS Servers. Are the clients configured to use the new DC for DNS? --> Yes

Comment: @syneticon-dj DC2003: dcdiag -> http://pastebin.com/uZWYqWTS netdiag -> http://pastebin.com/ERDfDMRf The outputs from DC2008R2-2 will follow tomorrow (here in germany ;) )

Comment: @syneticon-dj here it comes, DC2008R2-2: dcdiag -> http://pastebin.com/RpG88ih9 thanks for having a look!

Comment: looking at the errors from dcdiag it seems a bit like you get the wrong set of policies applying to them. Did you move the DCs out of the "Domain Controllers" OU or have changed the Default Domain Controllers Policy in any way? Running `dcgpofix` would restore it to default values - you should run a system state backup and try that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there are either DNS or replication problems. Here are some things to check:

**Did you add the new domain controller to the DNS resolvers list on all of your servers?**

If not, this is obviously the first thing to fix. Member servers should be configured to query all ADI DNS servers in its site.

**Are there replication problems with your DCs?**

If you have more than one DC, then they should each use each other for DNS to prevent replication islands. If your DCs are configured to use themselves first for resolution, then in a rapidly changing topology like you describe, replication can fail and all kinds of fun stuff will happen.